# How can i swap from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

im having trouble understanding the concept of fragments and all of the videos that i have watched/questions i have googled dont help me.

i want to swap from one fragment to another and all videos i find to that topic only cover from "main activity" to "fragment one".

As i have learned you are not able to just use "findViewById" you have to use view.findViewById ...

When i now want to set up a button which will swap from one activity to another i would write the code as the following:

```
 binding.buttonStart.setOnClickListener {
        
    }
```

But now im stuck. i dont know how i should go on from here. In the videos i find to that topic most people use "supportFragmentmanager", but as it seems to me, this is only availabe on the mainactivity/ on non fragment classes.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- If an Activity has mutliple child fragments use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

eg: Activity1 uses Fragment1 and Fragment2 you can use the supportFragmentManager of Activity1 to replace Fragment1 to Fragment2 or vice versa on Activity1.

- If a Fragment has mutliple child fragments use `getChildFragmentManager()`

eg: Activity1 uses Fragment1 which in turn uses Fragment1A and Fragment1B, here you can use childFragmentManager of Fragment1 to show child / replace Fragment1A and Fragment1B on Fragment1.